# How to grab files from Google Drive with PHP?

Tags: google-drive-api

I just need a starting place. How would you grab files from Google Drive with PHP? So, you would result in this:

```
<audio src='Google Drive File'></audio>
```

**I'm just starting programming. Any help would be appreciated...**

Comment: Share what have you tired? you try, we try

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way SO works is that you need to ask very specific questions, for which the community will provide very specific answers. Questions asking for general help will get down-voted and closed, not because they aren't good questions, but because there are better places to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you manually sharing just a few specific files or do you want to fetch the file's link dynamically/using lookups, etc.?

For the first, you can use the [Google Drive Direct Link Generator](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/).

The other option is to [modify the URL yourself](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/) so that something with a shared link like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing` becomes `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID`.

If purely non-manual and only in PHP, use the [Drive SDK for PHP (beta)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) or via the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing), has PHP examples.